# curl Google Drive rest API requests is too large

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I have problem with Google drive API. I have following code:

```
`curl -O http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100Mb.db

file="test100Mb.db"
mime_type=`file -b --mime $file`
howlong=`wc -c $file | cut -d' ' -f1`

echo $mime_type
echo $howlong
token=%token%
echo $token


curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Content-Type: $mime_type"  -H "Content-Length: $howlong" https://www.googleapis.com//upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable -T test100Mb.db`
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create script that will automatically populate Google drive until will be full. Unfortunately it ends up with message request is too large. Another thing is that I currently don't know how I would rename file after upload.

Thank you for help

Comment: if your intention is to consume drive quota, you'll find it easier by repeatedly duplicating an existing file than by uploading.

Comment: My intention is to populate drive with some garbage file in order to have it full. You know how I coud do it with the copy?

Comment: upload a file that isn't too big for curl, then use the copy API call to duplicate it many times